# Gather and mutate multiple columns in R

Tags: r, tidyr

I have three measurements, each with two time points.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tableone)

test_1_pre <- c(1,5,8,2)
test_1_post <- c(2,7,3,6)
test_2_pre <- c(6,3,6,5)
test_2_post <- c(9,8,9,1)
test_3_pre <- c(12,2,4,6)
test_3_post <- c(4,7,6,6)

df <- data.frame(test_1_pre, test_1_post, test_2_pre,
                 test_2_post, test_3_pre, test_3_post)

df_2 <- df %>%
  gather(test_1_pre, test_1_post,
         key="test_1_old", value="test_1") %>%
  gather(test_2_pre, test_2_post,
         key="test_2_old", value="test_2") %>%
  gather(test_3_pre, test_3_post,
         key="test_3_old", value="test_3") %>%
  mutate(pre_post = case_when(test_1_old == "test_1_pre" ~ 'pre',
                              test_1_old == "test_1_post" ~'post',
                              test_1_old == "test_2_pre" ~ 'pre',
                              test_1_old == "test_2_post" ~ 'post',
                              test_1_old == "test_3_pre" ~ 'pre',
                              test_1_old == "test_3_post" ~'post'))

vars_df <- c("test_1", "test_2", "test_3")


table_df <- CreateTableOne(vars = vars_df,
                                 data = df_2,
                                 strata = "pre_post")

tabelle.table_df<-print(table_df)
```

My aim is to get a table which compares the two time points "pre" and "post" of the different tests.

It works for test 1, but not the following ones.

Could anyone help, would be much appreciated!

```
Result:

                    Stratified by pre_post
                     post        pre         p      test
  n                    16          16                   
  test_1 (mean (sd)) 4.50 (2.13) 4.00 (2.83)  0.576     
  test_2 (mean (sd)) 5.88 (2.75) 5.88 (2.75)  1.000     
  test_3 (mean (sd)) 5.88 (2.85) 5.88 (2.85)  1.000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises because the `pre_post` column you create is incorrect for tests 2 and 3, which you can verify by inspecting the `df_2` dataframe. For example row 5 from your output is:

```r
test_1_post      2  test_2_pre      6  test_3_pre     12     post
```

Whilst a single data pipeline is appropriate is many circumstances, this problem is more easily solved by splitting up the tables and using a `union_all`, as per the following:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tableone)

test_1_pre <- c(1,5,8,2)
test_1_post <- c(2,7,3,6)
test_2_pre <- c(6,3,6,5)
test_2_post <- c(9,8,9,1)
test_3_pre <- c(12,2,4,6)
test_3_post <- c(4,7,6,6)

df <- data.frame(test_1_pre, test_1_post, test_2_pre,
                 test_2_post, test_3_pre, test_3_post)

get_dfs <- function(df, suffix) {
  df %>% 
    select(ends_with(suffix)) %>% 
    mutate(pre_post = suffix) %>% 
    # Drop _pre / _post suffixes in test column names ahead of union
    rename_with(.fn = function(x) gsub(paste0("_", suffix), "", x),
                .cols = starts_with("test"))
}

df_2 <- union_all(get_dfs(df, "pre"), get_dfs(df, "post"))

vars_df <- c("test_1", "test_2", "test_3")

table_df <- CreateTableOne(vars = vars_df,
                           data = df_2,
                           strata = "pre_post")

table_df
```

The output given is:

```r
# Stratified by pre_post
# post        pre         p      test
# n                     4           4                   
# test_1 (mean (SD)) 4.50 (2.38) 4.00 (3.16)  0.809     
# test_2 (mean (SD)) 6.75 (3.86) 5.00 (1.41)  0.427     
# test_3 (mean (SD)) 5.75 (1.26) 6.00 (4.32)  0.915
```

This contains more conservative p-values arising from the different estimated standard errors, as compared with @Frank's answer.

Moreover, the structure of `df_2` is cleaner:

```r
# test_1 test_2 test_3 pre_post
#      1      6     12      pre
#      5      3      2      pre
#      8      6      4      pre
#      2      5      6      pre
#      2      9      4     post
#      7      8      7     post
#      3      9      6     post
#      6      1      6     post
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. When I try to run it, I get an error (Error in rename_witz, couldnt find function rename_with). Do you perhaps know why this could be the case?

Comment: Did you type it out or copy-paste? I would recommend the latter approach. Looks like you're mispelling `rename_with`. Alternatively, if it's just misspelled in the comment, check you have loaded `tidyverse` (more specifically `dplyr`) in your current session. docs for this function are at https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/rename.html

Comment: I didn't have the latest dplyr package installed, now it works, thanks!

Comment: Great. Glad it helped. Please also consider accepting the answer if you think it definitively answers your initial question.

Answer (score 1):

```
nr <- c("1", "2", "3", "4")
test_1_pre <- c(1,5,8,2)
test_1_post <- c(2,7,3,6)
test_2_pre <- c(6,3,6,5)
test_2_post <- c(9,8,9,1)
test_3_pre <- c(12,2,4,6)
test_3_post <- c(4,7,6,6)

df <- data.frame(nr, test_1_pre, test_1_post, test_2_pre,
                 test_2_post, test_3_pre, test_3_post)

df_2 <- df %>%
  gather(test_1_pre, test_1_post, test_2_pre, test_2_post,
         test_3_pre, test_3_post,
         key="score", value="value") %>%
  mutate(pre_post = case_when(score == "test_1_pre" ~ 'pre',
                              score == "test_1_post" ~'post',
                              score == "test_2_pre" ~ 'pre',
                              score == "test_2_post" ~ 'post',
                              score == "test_3_pre" ~ 'pre',
                              score == "test_3_post" ~'post'))%>%
  pivot_wider(names_from="score", values_from="value")%>%
  gather(test_1_pre, test_1_post,
         key="test_1_old", value="test_1") %>%
  gather(test_2_pre, test_2_post,
         key="test_2_old", value="test_2") %>%
  gather(test_3_pre, test_3_post,
         key="test_3_old", value="test_3")

vars_df <- c("test_1", "test_2", "test_3")


table_df <- CreateTableOne(vars = vars_df,
                                 data = df_2,
                                 strata = "pre_post")

tabelle.table_df<-print(table_df)
```

Found the solution: first gather everything into one column, mutate the new column, spread the columns again and gather them separately.

```
                   Stratified by pre_post
                     post        pre         p      test
  n                    32          32                   
  test_1 (mean (SD)) 4.50 (2.13) 4.00 (2.83)  0.576     
  test_2 (mean (SD)) 6.75 (3.45) 5.00 (1.26)  0.067     
  test_3 (mean (SD)) 5.75 (1.13) 6.00 (3.86)  0.805
```

Comment: This answer needlessly introduces many redundant rows containing NAs in df_2 and as a consequence, provides incorrect estimates of the standard error. The incorrect estimates of SD and overly low p-values arise from `tableone` treating your data as if you have 32 pre- and 32 post-treatment observations as you can see in the values under `post` and `pre` in the printed output.